# use acronyms in redefined names

Tags: acronyms

I use

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Fig.~\arabic{figure}}
```

at the moment to renumber figures.

Is it possible to use an acronym for `Fig.` like `\ac{Fig.}`, so it reads `Figure` the first time and `Fig.` after that?

**Edit 1**: If I use the above command, everything is abbreviated with `Fig.`. `Figure` is used absolutely nowhere.

**Edit 2** Minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\ac{Fig.}~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}\figureautorefname{}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}\figurename{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \caption{First empty figure}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

There's \autoref{fig:first}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \caption{Second empty figure}
  \label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

There also is \autoref{fig:first}

\listoffigures

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{Fig.}{Figure}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, wouldn't your definition of `\thefigure` not double the word `Figure` or `Fig` then? Welcome to TeX.SX! We need more information on your document. In principle the `acronym` package could be of use

Comment: I also renewed the caption name `\figureautorefname` to `{}` so nothing will be doubled here. But instead of reading `Figure` the first time, it says `Fig.` all the time (See edit).

Comment: The `\figureautorefname` information was not available to me before you commented...that's the reason users should provide an MWE